# Accessing DLLs from different folders even after deploying without dynamic loading

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

My Windows application resides in the path "C:\Program Files\Test" and the DLLs are in a different location "C:\Program Files\ThirdPartyapplication". when the test application executes, all the DLLs must be retrieved from third party folder even after deploying and a local copy should not be maintained. Can this be achieved without dynamic loading?

**Note**: The DLLs gets updated often in the third party application folder, so My requirement is not to build my project every time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The following Microsoft doc comprehensively answers your question and offers 3 different methods.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/837908/how-to-load-an-assembly-at-runtime-that-is-located-in-a-folder-that-is

How to load an assembly at runtime that is located in a folder that is not the bin folder of the application

- Method 1: Install the assembly in the global assembly cache (GAC)
- Method 2: Use an application configuration (.config) file with the  tags
- Method 3: Use the AssemblyResolve event

Comment: In there its asking for a strong name... If my vendor provides a strong name key ... will there be a need to refer/change  it  in my application every time there is a version change of those dll's and build the application?